# Trouble with getting codes for Huffman Tree

Tags: recursion, tree, binary-tree, huffman-code

I need to create the codes to compress a Huffman Tree. (O if you traverse left 1 if you traverse right.)

Right now the codes array will get the correct first code, but afterwards will only return null.

I am not allowed to use any `instance/global` variables or any predefined java classes besides array and arrayList

```
public static String compress(final BinaryNodeInterface<Character> root, final String message)
{
    String[] codes;
    ArrayList<Character> letter = new ArrayList<Character>();
    String codeString = "";
    boolean addChar=true;

    for(int i =0; i<message.length();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<letter.size();j++)
            if(message.charAt(i)==letter.get(j))
                addChar=false;
            else
                addChar=true;
        if(addChar)               
            letter.add(message.charAt(i));
    }

    codes = new String[letter.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<letter.size();i++)
        codes[i]=(getPath(root,letter.get(i),""));

    return "";  // Do not forget to change this line!!!
}

private static String getPath(final BinaryNodeInterface<Character> root, char toFind, String path)
{
    String result;
    if (! root.isLeaf()) {
        if ((result = getPath(root.getLeftChild(),toFind, path + '0')) == null) {
            result = getPath(root.getLeftChild(),toFind, path + '1');
        }
    }
    else {
        result = (toFind == root.getData()) ? path : null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be visiting the right sub child. Change

```
result = getPath(root.getLeftChild(),toFind, path + '1');
```

to

```
result = getPath(root.getRightChild(),toFind, path + '1');
```

Comment: Thank you, thats the second dumb mistake I made so far.